# Changing immutable members inside the constructor

Tags: constructor, initialization, pass-by-reference, d, immutability

```
void increment(ref int i)
{
    ++i;
}

class Class
{
    immutable int member;

    this(int parameter)
    {
        member = parameter;
        ++member;           // okay
        increment(member);  // compile-time error
    }
}
```

Why is `++member` okay, but `increment(member)` isn't? Shouldn't both behave the same way?

Comment: But that would make things too easy. :P

Comment: Interesting enough this works: `void increment(int i, out int j) { j = i + 1; }`, and you call it with `increment(member, member)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because the reference to `increment` isn't `scope`, so it has the potential to be escaped past the scope of the constructor, which would break the immutability of `member`, and the compiler can't verify that it's fine.

(It might be that `scope` won't work either, but it *should*. If implemented properly, I think `scope` would fix a **lot** of bugs like these, as well as providing for interesting optimizations. If it doesn't, I'd say it's a bug.)

I've pointed out semi-similar bugs before, but with delegates.
Const/immutable do have such problems in D.

Answer (score 3):

What if `increment` was this?

```
int* p;
void increment(ref int i)
{
    p = &i;
}
```

Uh oh, you've created a mutable reference to immutable data, breaking the type system.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that

```
this(int parameter) {
    member = parameter;
    ++member;
}
```

is an equivalent of

```
Class(int parameter): member(parameter+1) {}
```

in C++.

I think `member` field is not truly mutable in constructor, so compiler can optimize it to just init it. But it cannot do it with call to another function.

PS. It works on ideone: http://ideone.com/5ym5u

Comment: Ideone has a little older version - 2.042. So I think I'll go with Peter Alexander's answer.